# Strange Embedded SQL situation

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have an SQLRPGLE program that updates a pallet file to change the status field for all pallets in a given location EXCEPT for the (up to) 4 that the user has entered when prompted.

If the user enters 2-4 pallets it works like a charm, but every time the user only enters  1 pallet, it return an sqlcde of 100 (no records found for update.)  I have debugged the code and actually copy and pasted (changing the variables) in the SQL shell and still it works fine outside the program but not inside.

In the code below, P1 is true when 1 pallet entered p2 when 2 and so on...

```
             if (Error=*off);
           strline=%char(XLINE);
           select;

             when p4=true;
             exec sql
             update plt set ptstat='0'
             where ptloc=:strLINE and
             ptplt not in (:xpal1, :xpal2, :xpal3, :Xpal4);
             if sqlcod<>0;
               msgnbr='SQL0001';
               exsr MSG;
               leave;
             endif;

             when p3=true;
             exec sql
             update plt set ptstat='0'
             where ptloc=:strLINE and
             ptplt not  in (:xpal1, :xpal2, :xpal3);
             if sqlcod<>0;
               msgnbr='SQL0001';
               exsr MSG;
               leave;
             endif;

             when p2=true;
             exec sql
             update plt set ptstat='0'
             where ptloc=:strLINE and
             ptplt  not in (:xpal1, :xpal2);
             if sqlcod<>0;
               msgnbr='SQL0001';
               exsr MSG;
               leave;
             endif;

             when p1=true;
             exec sql
             update plt set ptstat='0'
             where ptloc=:strLINE and
             ptplt  not in (:xpal1);
             if sqlcod<>0;
               msgnbr='SQL0001';
               exsr MSG;
               leave;
             endif;

             other;

           ENDSL;
```

Any ideas?

I forgot to mention....originally the code for 1 pallet was:

```
             when p1=true;
             exec sql
             update plt set ptstat='0'
             where ptloc=:strLINE and
             ptplt<>:xpal1;
             if sqlcod<>0;
               msgnbr='SQL0001';
               exsr MSG;
               leave;
             endif;
```

but that didn't work, so I changed it to the first example trying to keep it as similar to the working code as possible.

Comment: I see nothing obvious in the code you posted.  Did you post the actual code (via copy & paste) or a simplified version (or hand typed)?  What values does the debugger show for all variables with both 1 pallet and 2+ pallets?

Comment: It's copy and paste...and the values in the debug where dead right...in fact they where cut from one session and pasted into the STRSQL shell as well....I love when computers act as unpredictable as people....

Comment: We need to see actual debug values and variable definitions. Variable values/definitions for p1, true, strLINE, ptloc, xpal1 and ptplt at least should be shown. (Possibly in hex.) Also, does debug show that the appropriate SELECT path is entered? Since each path seems to send the same MSG, it's not possible for anyone to be sure what path is taken without some kind of trace.

Comment: if you're still curious what caused this, it would also be helpful to tell us what the SQLSTATE, SQLCODE, or other error messages were.

Comment: As a side note, you probably shouldn't be checking for a strict `SQLCOD <> 0` - there's other warnings that can probably be generated.  Heck, I think one of them might be "recalculating plan", which might crop up here.  `< 0` is usually okay (as it indicates a "hard" error, usually), but anything `> 0` should be ignored (100s are often prime candidates - we had a program that logged all not-founds, even when that was the _expected_ result...) or potentially handled separately, if you care about that specific message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simplifying your code so that you dont need four different UPDATE statements?

If the user doesnt supply all four values, copy the first value into the other empty fields.  Now you can say

```
ptplt not in (:xpal1, :xpal2, :xpal3, :Xpal4);
```

You should get correct results regardless of whether any of those for variables hold identical values.

Comment: The answer should avoid the problem and is how I'd probably have coded in the first place. But does it answer the OP's question, "Why doesn't this work with one and only one value?"

Comment: I'm going to do this, because I agree that it will fix the business situation, but I would still love to know whay the original issue even existed....and now, why would you choose to write the values into missing variables instead of using a select and executing different update statements? Just curious, as I would figure my original way actually executes less code than the way you suggest. It's not going to be a big preformance hit, but I always lean to the less is better unless the readability of the code is signifigantly hurt...so just curious about the reasoning..

Comment: I quite understand the desire to figure out a mystery.  I would suggest this is a better solution.  It is less RPG code, less SQL code, simpler logic.  These are things that generally lead to fewer bugs, lower cost of maintenance.  Developer time is more expensive than the marginal CPU time at stake.  The smaller code footprint occupies less memory, requires fewer SQE execution plans and increasing chances of re-using pages already loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
 D mycnt           s             10i 0 inz( 0 )
 D myName          s             10a   inz( 'ACCP' )
  /free
   *inlr = *on ;

   EXEC SQL  Select count(*) into :mycnt
                 from ACCPTH where APFILE in(:myName) ;

   if SQLCODE = +100 and SQLSTATE = '02000' ;
      dsply 'None 1' ;
   endif ;
   if SQLERRD(3) > 0 ;
      dsply 'None 2' ;
   endif ;
   if mycnt > 0 ;
      dsply 'Found some' ;
   endif ;

   return ;
  /end-free
```

The ACCPTH test file was created by running DSPFD TYPE(*ACCPTH) against a library that had a file named 'ACCP' already in it. Debug showed that mycnt had the correct count at the point where the IF-statement tested it.

If the EXEC SQL and IF-tests portion is duplicated and a second myName2 variable is added for the additional code block, it continues to work correctly (for me). The myName2 variable would have a second file name (or a name that doesn't exist; it doesn't matter).

Additional details about your code are needed in order to guess why it's not working for you.